# Cannot get mysql service going, it worked before re-boot

Tags: boot, server, mysql

I've just re-booted my ubuntu 16:04 box and now can't load any of my webpages.  Seems the mysql hasn't started.

How can I de-bug this problem?

When I try to start it with the 'sudo service mysql start' command I get a red message, Failed to Start MySQL community server.

Annoyingly, it worked before the re-boot.  Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you should also see a hint where to find the error log files together with the message. Afaik should be in `/var/log/mysql` or something similar. Probably a corrupted config file which didn't get applied until the reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for check mysql status, open your terminal and type :

> sudo systemctl status mysql.service

the log directory for error is located in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, to show it you can use this command :

> cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Deki.  I am running the service on a virtual box and it looks like I "filled it up" so, this is a temporary solution.  I will ensure I don't install anything else, just leave it running, and stop "fixing it" the old adage of don't fix it unless it's broken comes to mind.  When I ran the error log you gave me, I thought that the screen was never going to stop scrolling ;-)

Comment: you're wellcome... the screen never going to stop scrolling?? I think there are Huge error on your log.... so it is make the screen scrolling, but it will be stop scrolling when all error was printed in your terminal..